# how to understand javascript memory leak in this circumstance

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I am trying to understand memory leak and I have read blogs as following:

- [How to handle 4 common memory leaks](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-memory-management-how-to-handle-4-common-memory-leaks-3f28b94cfbec)
- [Avoiding Memory Leaks in JavaScript](https://appendto.com/2016/11/avoiding-memory-leaks-in-javascript/)

Unfortunately, I still feel confused on this issue.

So, I try to make a test like this:

1. Firstly, I create a pure HTML containing a huge table within a `div#box`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
      <table>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>

         ... hiden 2400 lines of same content row intended for simplicity ...

        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Then open the devTool and use `Console` and `Memory` to make actions and memory recoding:

```
// 1. Initial "heap snapshot" get 1.9MB

// 2. Running following code on "Console" and "heap snapshot" get 2.2MB
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var tab = document.querySelector("table");
box.removeChild(tab);
tab = null;

// 3. Running following code on "Console" and  "heap snapshot" get 2.2MB
box.parentElement.removeChild(box);
box = null;
```

My confusing is why I almost empty this html DOM tree but the memory consumption is increased.

Any explanation about on JavaScript memory leak will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Browsers do not necessarily give memory back to the underlying operating system.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your comment. May I ask do you have any helpfull articals on this issues? I am trying to dig deep into it.